# Weird "too many indices for array" error issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've written a custom generator for keras
and in that there is this function:
it ran one or two iteration but stops saying
too many indices for array on this line

```
label = label[y:(y + dy), x:(x + dx)]
```

notice that all images and shapes have same dimensions!

```
def random_crop(image, edge, label, random_crop_size=(800, 1600)):
    # Note: image_data_format is 'channel_last'

    assert image.shape[2] == 3
    height, width = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]
    dy, dx = random_crop_size

    x = np.random.randint(0, width - dx + 1)
    y = np.random.randint(0, height - dy + 1)

    image = image[y:(y + dy), x:(x + dx), :]
    print(label.shape)
    print(y,y+dy)
    print(x,x+dx)
    label = label[y:(y + dy), x:(x + dx)]
    if edge is not None:
        edge = edge[y:(y + dy), x:(x + dx)]
        imagePlusEdge = np.zeros((random_crop_size[0], random_crop_size[1], 4))
        imagePlusEdge[:, :, :3] = image
        imagePlusEdge[:, :, -1] = edge[:, :]
        return imagePlusEdge, label
    return image, label
```

Comment: What is the output of print(label.shape)?

Comment: the output is (1024, 2048),label = label[y:(y + dy), x:(x + dx)] solved my problem! but weird is it happens after few iteration not on first with label = label[y:(y + dy), x:(x + dx);0]

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error if your `label` is 2D(i. e. the shape of your label does not let you pass a third indice) or has dimensions/shape smaller then `image`.

Comment: image (1024,2048,3),label and edge (1024,2048), but dimension is not the case, because it runs for few iterations

Comment: can you give me the values of `x`, `y`, `dx` and `dy`, while it's iterating?